# Excel VB works fine on SharePoint. Move to my C;Drive change the path and it does not

Tags: vba, excel

You helped me create this set of code. The workbooks are on a sharepoint and they work fine.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim DestWb As Workbook 'define destination workbook
    Set DestWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\Paul Webb\Cats Protection\Crawley Branch Site - Finance Documents\Adoptions\Testing Area\summary sheet - testing .xls")

    Dim DestWs As Worksheet 'define destination worksheet
    Set DestWs = DestWb.Worksheets("Datainput")

    Dim eRow As Long 'determine last row in destination worksheet
    eRow = DestWs.Cells(DestWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    'If eRow >= 1 Then eRow = eRow + 1

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Datasheet").Range("B1:B48").Copy 'copy directly before paste
    DestWs.Cells(eRow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, Skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=True

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    DestWb.Close Save = True 'close and save destination workbook
End Sub
```

I have moved the files to my c drive and change the path in the code. But when I run the code I can see that it opens the target workbook but does not paste any of the data in to the spreadsheet. What have I missed please?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim DestWb As Workbook 'define destination workbook
    Set DestWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Cats Protection\Adoption\summary sheet - testing.xlsx")

    Dim DestWs As Worksheet 'define destination worksheet
    Set DestWs = DestWb.Worksheets("Datainput")

    Dim eRow As Long 'determine last row in destination worksheet
    eRow = DestWs.Cells(DestWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    'If eRow >= 1 Then eRow = eRow + 1

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Datasheet").Range("B1:B48").Copy 'copy directly before paste
    DestWs.Cells(eRow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, Skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=True

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    DestWb.Close Save = True 'close and save destination workbook
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Both codes** have the issue that `DestWb.Close Save = True` is actually not doing what you assume, because you used it the wrong way.

I highly recommend to use `Option Explicit` (as first line in every VBA module/worksheet). This would have warned you because in your code `Save` is a not declared variable (instead of a parameter name).

---

**Some background how to submit parameters to the `.Close` method**

According to the documentation the [Workbook.Close Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-close-method-excel) accepts the following parameters:

```
.Close(SaveChanges, Filename, RouteWorkbook)
```

So you have 2 possibilities to submit the parameters:

1. By parameter order (without parameter name), order as in documentation

   ```
   .Close True, "C:\Temp\file.xlsx"
   .Close "C:\Temp\file.xlsx", True '!! wrong parameter order !!
   ```
2. By parameter name (order of parameters is not relevant now)

   ```
   .Close Filename:="C:\Temp\file.xlsx", SaveChanges:=True
   .Close SaveChanges:=True, Filename:="C:\Temp\file.xlsx"
   ```

   Both lines are equal.

Please not that parameters for a method must be set with a `:=` instead of like variables are set with a `=` only. Also the parameter name is `SaveChanges` not `Save`.

---

**What was the issue with your code?**

In `DestWb.Close Save = True` your `Save` is a variable. Because it was not declared nor initialized it is `Nothing`. So `Save = True` actually evaluates to `False` and parameters are submitted by order, so it is actually the same like `DestWb.Close False` which means: *"Close and don't save the workbook"*.

Comment: Does this explain that by changing to Save = False it is working. Because the way I have  constructed the code the False is meaning True?

Comment: Actually `Save = False` should evaluate to `True` (test it by `Debug.Print Save = False` it returns `True`) but then your code only works **by accident** and you still doing it *extremely* wrong. Don't do that! The only correct ways are `.Close True` or `.Close SaveChanges:=True` anything else is wrong and must not be used.